# How do I Identify a Non-schema-bound dependency

Tags: sql, sql-server

In an inherited database I've looked at `Objects on which [Table1] depends`

It has a couple of other tables listed, and clicking on each table shows me the dependency type is: `Non-schema-bound dependency`

When viewing create statements and ER-Diagrams for these tables, I can't see a link at all, so what the heck IS the link and how do I identify it?!!

Comment: When you script a `CREATE` statement (in SSMS) for a table won't create the other objects it depends on, only that object.

Comment: In the past, I've pulled the create statement to identify foreign keys (could just look at ER diagram but I tried that and there was no links on it)

Comment: That doesn't mean there are other tables that reference that table as a foreign key. Or perhaps there are scalar functions for constraints/default values. Very difficult to give an answer when we can't see what you do.